# How to hide element in Vue-html-to-paper?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, plugins

I need to hide some things when I do print pages. The 2 button signs do not want to be displayed when I want to print. I use plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-html-to-paper

Check my code:

```
<div id="printThis">
 <h1> My tiyle </h1>
 <button> I WAN'T TO DISPLAY THIS BUTTON IN PRINT!!! </button>
 <p> My parag </p>
</div>


print(){
  this.$htmlToPaper('printThis');
}
```

Question is simple. I wan't display button in my pdf paper.

Answer (score 0):

I've read through the source code at https://github.com/mycurelabs/vue-html-to-paper/blob/master/src/index.js and it doesn't look like there's a variable built in to do this (which there really should be, maybe you could make a pull request?). But we can make one ourselves.

In the `data` section of your component, add a variable called `printing`:

```
  data() {
    return {
      printing: false,
    }
  },
```

Edit your template to use it:

```
<template>
<div id="printThis">
 <h1> My tiyle </h1>
 <button v-show="!printing"> I WAN'T TO DISPLAY THIS BUTTON IN PRINT!!! </button>
 <p> My parag </p>
</div>
</template>
```

(Note you can use v-if too. There's some upsides and some downsides.)

Then wrap the method call to the plugin in a method of your own to set and unset the variable. Use the callback the plugin documentation describes to unset the variable:

```
print(){
  this.printing = true;
  const options = null; // Set this if you need to, based on https://randomcodetips.com/vue-html-to-paper/
  this.$htmlToPaper('printThis', options, () => {
    this.printing = false;
  });
}
```

And there you go.

I will say, you could probably write a plugin way better to do the same thing. It'd be nice to have a promise based approach, or at least some defined lifecycle events for print success or failure.

Comment: Could you explain what's not working so I can help?

Comment: Your method with this 
  this.printing = true;
  const options = null; // Set this if you need to, based on https://randomcodetips.com/vue-html-to-paper/
  this.$htmlToPaper('printThis', options, () => {
    this.printing = false;
  });

After this i dont see my element in print .

Comment: Check my answear of admin this plugin...
https://github.com/mycurelabs/vue-html-to-paper/issues/42#issuecomment-611701830

Comment: I'm sorry, I need a little bit more detail to go on... The maintainer of the library even gave the same answer I did. We need more detail to know why it's not working for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify css file direction and in css file write your option.

Something like this.

__dir/app.js or __dir/main.js

```js
import VueHtmlToPaper from 'vue-html-to-paper';

const options = {
  name: '_blank',
  specs: [
    'fullscreen=yes',
    'titlebar=yes',
    'scrollbars=yes'
  ],
  styles: [
    'css/print.css',
  ]
}

Vue.use(VueHtmlToPaper, options);
```

```css
    @media print {
        .hidden-print {
            display: none !important;
        }
    }
```